# Strange server behaviour after keyboard was connected - was server compromised or data centre at fault?

Tags: kernel, logs, tty, shutdown

This morning I received a notification from our host that they couldn't ping the server, I've checked the logs and 5 minutes before the following happened:

```
Jun 13 10:34:50 server-name kernel: usb 1-5: new low-speed USB device number 2 using xhci_hcd
Jun 13 10:34:50 server-name kernel: input: Logitech USB Keyboard as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.0/0003:046D:C31C.0001/input/input0
Jun 13 10:34:50 server-name kernel: hid-generic 0003:046D:C31C.0001: input: USB HID v1.10 Keyboard [Logitech USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-5/input0
Jun 13 10:34:50 server-name kernel: input: Logitech USB Keyboard Consumer Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.1/0003:046D:C31C.0002/input/input1
Jun 13 10:34:50 server-name kernel: input: Logitech USB Keyboard System Control as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:14.0/usb1/1-5/1-5:1.1/0003:046D:C31C.0002/input/input2
Jun 13 10:34:50 server-name kernel: hid-generic 0003:046D:C31C.0002: input: USB HID v1.10 Device [Logitech USB Keyboard] on usb-0000:00:14.0-5/input1
Jun 13 10:34:50 server-name init: tty (/dev/tty1) main process (1884) killed by TERM signal
Jun 13 10:34:50 server-name init: tty (/dev/tty2) main process (1886) killed by TERM signal
Jun 13 10:34:50 server-name init: tty (/dev/tty3) main process (1891) killed by TERM signal
Jun 13 10:34:50 server-name init: tty (/dev/tty4) main process (1893) killed by TERM signal
Jun 13 10:34:50 server-name init: tty (/dev/tty5) main process (1895) killed by TERM signal
Jun 13 10:34:50 server-name init: tty (/dev/tty6) main process (1897) killed by TERM signal
```

Does this mean someone at the datacentre plugged a keyboard in and this happened or has it been compromised? The server was not resposive for an hour later, it couldn't be rebooted either

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: it certainly looks like someone plugged a usb keyboard into your server.  and maybe pressed Ctrl-Alt-Del to reboot it (and since it hasn't come back up, maybe powered it down while it was rebooting).   You should contact your data center about it - most likely someone plugged their kbd into the *wrong* server and it was just a simple mistake, or it could be something more malicious than that.  No one here will have the answer to that, but your DC should know who had physical access at the time.